# Call asynchronous method with mock callout class

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, salesforce-lightning

I am currently writing a mock callout class to test an API call that is being pushed into a production environment. The problem that I am having is the class that has the API call in it is an asynchronous class that implements queueable: `public void execute(QueueableContext sc){}`.

When I go to call the method, I am not sure what to put inside the parenthesis: `HttpResponse res = NewDonorLetter2.execute();`. If I put nothing, I receive the error *Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void execute() from the type NewDonorLetter2*. This makes sense because something needs to be passed to it but I cannot figure out what to put.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't do anything special with `QueueableContext` in your method (get the job id, query status of the job in `ApexJob` table, send an email that job succeeded...) - call it passing a null. It'll match the method's signature (you're calling the version with 1 parameter, which just happens to be useless).

There's difference between `myMethod()` and `myMethod(null)`. It's bit like the trick to have Batchable and Schedulable in one class (you DON'T need a separate Schedulable class). They both need an `execute` method.

```apex
public with sharing class MyClass Implements Database.batchable<sObject>, Schedulable{

    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) { 
        Database.executeBatch(this);
    }

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM User]);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> scope) {
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    }
}
```

SF will know which one I want depending on whether I call `new MyClass().execute(null);` or `new MyClass.execute(null, [SELECT Id FROM User LIMIT 5]);`

Comment: I added null to that function and now I am receiving another error that says "Non static method cannot be referenced from a static context". I am not able change the method that contains the API call to static, so is the way that I am calling the method incorrect?

Comment: Do it like I did. New instance of the class and call execute on that. If you don't need the variable hanging around for anything else - it becomes a 1-liner. `new NewDonorLetter2().execute(null);`?

Comment: Do I make a new class with the code you have above, or add it to the one I currently have?

Comment: Delete your line that doesn't compile (HttpResponse res = NewDonorLetter2.execute();) and put mine instead.

Comment: When I add that I get an error saying "Invalid type: NewDonorLetter2.execute". In the code that you responded with in the post, is that supposed to be in a new class or the class that contains the api call?

Comment: I'm bit lost, what do you have problem with, maybe post more code? To call a queueable in normal code use `System.enqueueJob(new NewDonorLetter2());`. To call just the working part of a queueable directly (reuse it in test or another code that doesn't need it to be asynchronous) do `new NewDonorLetter2().execute(null);`. You can do it in a test too or `Test.startTest(); (code with System.enqueueJob in it) Test.stopTest();`.You seen https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm ?

Comment: I apologize but I am confused as well. I need help building a mock class that is able to fake an API call. The API call is built into a class and when it is run in production it is not directly called. The main class is called, which runs code to pull some information needed for the API call, and then the API function is ran. All of the examples I have found for the mock class directly call the function that contains the API call.  I dont believe I am able to do that. I could post a new question where I am able to include the class that contains the API call if that would help?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with Queueable. Create a class similar to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm (replace `{"example":"test"}` with something smilar to what your api is returning). and put a `Test.setMock` line at beginning of your test method. All callouts (from main code or from queueables) will be intercepted and sent to your mock class. Meaning if you need more than 1 response you could build some ifs in the mock and return stuff depending on `req.getEndpoint()`

Comment: I have tried implementing the `Test.setMock` with no luck, I am now receiving the error "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void setMock(System.Type, MockHttpResponseGenerator) from the type test".  The mock callout class is exactly how it is in the example with the only difference being the URL that is being called.  Is using apex code the only way to make callouts?

Comment: update your question with relevant bit of the test class, mock class and the bit of the "real" code making the callout. I suspect you did a stupid and created a class/variable/visualforce page named "Test" and then "Test.setMock(...)" tries to hit that instead of the real one... (You could try System.Test.setMock(...)" but it'd be better to find and destroy this custom thing you made.

Comment: You are a genius. The reason it was not working was because there was a class named test that did absolutely nothing and once i removed that it worked. I was able to get everything pushed to production. Now its just waiting to see if everything works correctly. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Lol. I mean glad I could help but... Lol ;)